# Form login in spring security doesn't work

Tags: spring-security

I have a problem with Spring Security in the form login: they don't find the URL login even if I give them the path

```
<form-login login-page="/login"  default-target-url="/index"  />
```

when I execute the browser gives `:\ :`

> Cette page Web présente une boucle de redirection.

English translation of above to assist debug:

```
This web page has a redirect loop.
```

this is controller :

```
@Controller
public class LoginController{

            @RequestMapping("/login")
            public String doLogin() {
                return "login";
            }
}
```

this is spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd" >
        <http pattern="/images/**" security="none"/>
        <http pattern="/styles/**" security="none"/>
        <http pattern="/js/**" security="none"/>
        <http pattern="/login" security="none" />

        <http  auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
                <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
                <form-login login-page="/login.jsp"  default-target-url="/index" authentication-failure-url="/login"  /> 

                <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/index"/>
        </http>

        <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
            <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" ></beans:property>

        </beans:bean>
        <beans:bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <beans:property name="providers">
                    <beans:list>
                    <beans:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
                    </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
        <beans:bean  id="userDetailsService" class="com.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></beans:bean>
        <authentication-manager>        
                    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
                            <password-encoder hash="md5"></password-encoder>
                    </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Did you tried to clear the cache?

Comment: yes @yassine__ :\ but nothing change

Comment: can you please show us your security code configuration as well as your security controller (if you have one).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 1: Based on user input

Change the following line

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
```

to something along these lines

or

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER_ADMIN')"/>
```

Basically take out isAuthenticated() out of it as reading XML configurations few people have had issues with it.

Let me know if it fixes it.

Extra examples: [Spring security wont redirect on intercept-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255656/spring-security-wont-redirect-on-intercept-url)

Comment: Failed to evaluate expression 'USER_ADMIN' !!

Comment: i've edited the new intercept-url. If i were you i'd scrap xml and go java config. Personally i hated XML.